# Syntax: hash (pound) then symbol

Tags: clojure, datomic

I was following the Datomic sample schema and there's an ID for an entity defined as

```
:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
```

What's the meaning of *#db/id*? The schema is loaded with read-string, so I guess it's valid Clojure syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a new feature in Clojure 1.4: [a reader literal](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#21-reader-literals).

Answer (score 1):

Jouni is right, it's a [reader literal](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#21-reader-literals).

More specifically, the reader literal **#db/id[:db.part/db]** will create a temporary entity id within the **:db.part/db** partition.

This temporary id can be used when building a transaction.  If the transaction is successfully applied to the database (ie. "transacted"), the temporary id will be replaced by a permanent entity id in the database.

The general form of this particular reader literal is **#db/id[partition-name value*]**, where value is an optional negative value that allows the temporary id to be uniquely and deterministically distinguished within a single transaction.

This is a great convenience, as eg. **#db/id[:db.part/user -300]** could be used in several places within a specific transaction to refer to the same not-yet-created entity.